# How to determine the most accurate collision of two circles?

Tags: swift, collision

I am creating a new game application in code! 
I created some bubbles using spriteKit. I used the texture for this.
They randomly fly around the playing field. When they intersect with each other, they must collide and change their path.

The first problem: of course, the image of a bubble in the shape of a circle. But in a collision, the bubbles touch each other’s faces not as a circle, but as a square

The second problem: they cling to each other, I think this is the problem of the first problem!

If you known how to fix this is problem please help my, because I can't find solve that problem. 
I think this problem can be solved with a Mask, but I don’t know how. Thanks a lot)

this is my bubbleClass:

```
class SKButton: SKSpriteNode{

private var buttonTexture:SKTexture

override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    self.buttonTexture = texture!

    super.init(texture:buttonTexture , color: .black, size: buttonTexture.size())

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

This is ViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mySKView: SKView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = mySKView {
        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}}
```

this is GameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
private var arrayBubbles = [SKButton?]()
private var arrayVelosity = [CGPoint]()
private var bubbleMovePointsPerSecX = [CGFloat]()
private var bubbleMovePointsPerSecY = [CGFloat]()

private var currentVelosity:CGPoint!

private var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
private var dt: TimeInterval = 0
private let min = 0
private let max = 3

private let bubbleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble")
private let playableRect: CGRect!

lazy var background: SKSpriteNode = {
    let back = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back")
    back.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    back.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    back.zPosition = -1
    return back
}()

lazy var bubble1: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear, size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height - (size.height/3))
    button.setScale(0)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble1"
    return button
}()

lazy var bubble2: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear, size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/3, y: size.height/2)
    button.setScale(0)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble2"
    return button
}()

lazy var bubble3: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear, size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width - (size.width/3), y: size.height/2)
    button.setScale(0)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble3"
    return button
}()

override init(size: CGSize) {
    let playableHeight = size.width/(16.0/9.0)
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight)/2

    playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
    super.init(size:size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChilds()
    appendBubblesToArray()
    setRandomBubbleSpead()
    appendVelosityToArray()
    showApearBubble()

}
private func addChilds(){
    addChild(background)
    addChild(bubble1)
    addChild(bubble2)
    addChild(bubble3)
}

private func appendBubblesToArray(){
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble1)
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble2)
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble3)
}

private func setRandomBubbleSpead(){
    for _ in min..<arrayBubbles.count{
        let randomSpeadX = CGFloat.random(in: -200..<200)/CGFloat(Double.pi)
        bubbleMovePointsPerSecX.append(randomSpeadX)

        let randomSpeadY = CGFloat.random(in: -200..<200)/CGFloat(Double.pi)
        bubbleMovePointsPerSecY.append(randomSpeadY)
    }
}

private func appendVelosityToArray(){
    for index in min..<arrayBubbles.count{
        currentVelosity = CGPoint(x: bubbleMovePointsPerSecX[index], y: bubbleMovePointsPerSecY[index])
        arrayVelosity.append(currentVelosity)
    }
}

private func showApearBubble(){
    let apearBubble = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.5)
    let action = [apearBubble]

    bubble1.run(SKAction.sequence(action))
    bubble2.run(SKAction.sequence(action))
    bubble3.run(SKAction.sequence(action))
}

override func didEvaluateActions() {
    checkColisions()
}

private func checkColisions(){
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") { [weak self] node, _ in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        switch node.name{
        case "bubble1":
            self.checkBubbleIntersection(self.bubble1)
            break
        case "bubble2":
            self.checkBubbleIntersection(self.bubble2)
            break
        case "bubble3":
            self.checkBubbleIntersection(self.bubble3)
            break
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}

private func hitBubble(_ index: Int){
    arrayVelosity[index].y = -arrayVelosity[index].y
    arrayVelosity[index].x = -arrayVelosity[index].x
}

private func checkBubbleIntersection(_ firstBubble: SKButton){
    for bubble in arrayBubbles {
        if firstBubble.name != bubble!.name{
            if firstBubble.frame.insetBy(dx: 80,dy: 80).intersects(bubble!.frame){
                guard let indexBubble = self.arrayBubbles.firstIndex(of: bubble) else { return }
                self.hitBubble(indexBubble)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if lastUpdateTime > 0{
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime

    } else{
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

    for bubble in arrayBubbles{
        if bubble != nil {
            guard let index = arrayBubbles.firstIndex(of: bubble) else { return }

            moveSprite(sprite: arrayBubbles[index]!, velosity: arrayVelosity[index])
            boundsCheckBubbles(sprite: arrayBubbles[index]!, index: index)
        }
    }
}

private func moveSprite(sprite: SKButton, velosity: CGPoint){
    let amountToMove = CGPoint(x: velosity.x * CGFloat(dt), y: velosity.y * CGFloat(dt))
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + amountToMove.x,
                              y: sprite.position.y + amountToMove.y)

}

private func boundsCheckBubbles(sprite: SKButton, index: Int){
    let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: 80, y: playableRect.minY)
    let topRight = CGPoint(x: size.width-80, y: playableRect.maxY)

    if sprite.position.x <= bottomLeft.x{
        sprite.position.x = bottomLeft.x
        arrayVelosity[index].x = -arrayVelosity[index].x
    }
    if sprite.position.x >= topRight.x{
        sprite.position.x = topRight.x
        arrayVelosity[index].x = -arrayVelosity[index].x
    }
    if sprite.position.y <= bottomLeft.y{
        sprite.position.y = bottomLeft.y
        arrayVelosity[index].y = -arrayVelosity[index].y
    }
    if sprite.position.y >= topRight.y{
        sprite.position.y = topRight.y
        arrayVelosity[index].y = -arrayVelosity[index].y
    }
}}
```

Comment: There's really not enough context with the code you've shared. You share the collision function but not where it's used, so it's hard to tell what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself was able to solve this problem.
But I found another way to solve this problem. I use a bitmask and collision!

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

private var arrayBubbles = [SKButton?]()

private var bubbleTexture = SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Oval"))
private let playableRect: CGRect!

let bubble1Category:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0;
let bubble2Category:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1;
let bubble3Category:UInt32 = 0x1 << 2;
let borderCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 10

var borderBody: SKPhysicsBody!

lazy var bubble1: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear, size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height - (size.height/3))
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble1"
    button.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubbleTexture.size().width/2)
    button.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bubble1Category
    button.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bubble2Category | bubble3Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = bubble2Category | bubble3Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    button.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    button.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    return button
}()

lazy var bubble2: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear, size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/3, y: size.height/2)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble2"
    button.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubbleTexture.size().width/2)
    button.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bubble2Category
    button.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bubble1Category | bubble3Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = bubble1Category | bubble3Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    button.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    button.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    return button
}()

lazy var bubble3: SKButton = {
    var button = SKButton(texture: bubbleTexture, color: .clear , size: bubbleTexture.size())
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width - (size.width/3), y: size.height/2)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "bubble3"
    button.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubbleTexture.size().width/2)
    button.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bubble3Category
    button.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bubble1Category | bubble2Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = bubble1Category | bubble2Category | borderCategory
    button.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    button.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    button.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    return button
}()

override init(size: CGSize) {
    let playableHeight = size.width/(16.0/9.0)
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight)/2

    playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
    super.init(size:size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)

    // Set border property
    setBorderBody()

    addChilds()
    appendBubblesToArray()
    showApearBubble()

    setFirstBubbleVelosity()
}

func setFirstBubbleVelosity(){
    for bubble in arrayBubbles{
        bubble!.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    }
}

func setBorderBody(){
    borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    borderBody.categoryBitMask = borderCategory
    borderBody.friction = 0.0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case bubble1Category | bubble2Category:
        bubble1.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble1Category | bubble3Category:
        bubble1.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble1Category | borderCategory:
        bubble1.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()

    case bubble2Category | bubble1Category:
        bubble2.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble2Category | bubble3Category:
        bubble2.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble2Category | borderCategory:
        bubble2.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()

    case bubble3Category | bubble1Category:
        bubble3.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble3Category | bubble2Category:
        bubble3.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    case bubble3Category | borderCategory:
        bubble3.physicsBody?.velocity = calculateRandomBubbleVelosity()
    default: print("Unknown contact detected")
    }
}

private func addChilds(){
    addChild(bubble1)
    addChild(bubble2)
    addChild(bubble3)
}

private func appendBubblesToArray(){
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble1)
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble2)
    arrayBubbles.append(bubble3)
}

private func calculateRandomBubbleVelosity() -> CGVector{
    let randomVelosityByX = CGFloat.random(in: -200..<200)
    let randomVelosityByY = CGFloat.random(in: -200..<200)
    let randomVelosity = CGVector(dx: randomVelosityByX * cos(100.0), dy: randomVelosityByY * sin(100.0))
    return randomVelosity
}

private func showApearBubble(){
    bubble1.setScale(1.5)
    bubble2.setScale(1.5)
    bubble3.setScale(1.5)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "bubble1") {  node, _ in

            let bubble = node as! SKButton
            if bubble.contains(touch.location(in: self)){

                //Some your logic

            }
        }
    }
}}
```